# How to flash(hide/clear/delete) the previously appended values on every new click?

Tags: php, jquery

Whenever I click, the new value  is appended but the previous value is also shown. How can I clear the previously appended values on every new click?

Here goes the onclick used in php function

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick=chat_com('$name'); >$name </a><br>";  // suppose this dispalyes a,b,c
```

Here is jquery function to append this value.

```
function chat_com(name) {
    $('#appendto').append(name);
}
```

Here is the HTML div where value is appended.

```
<div id="appendto"></div>
```

On first click `a` is shown, on second click `a,b` is shown instead just `b`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#appendto").empty().append(name);
```

Comment: now,shown problem has gone but previous value is also being inserted on every new click.Plz help

Comment: You should start a new question, and you'll need to provide more information: at least provide more of the related code.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
function chat_com(name) {
$("#appento").html("")

$('#appendto').append(name);

   }
```

or

```
  $('#appendto').empty().append(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of append use html. this will automatically flush older html.

```
$('#appendto').html(name);
```

Comment: @Sunshil now,shown problem has gone but previous value is also being inserted on every new click.I think i have to make pevious click or function null firstly if it is running.